# Batch calls to Google Cloud Storage API from C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I'm implementing an interface that will let us replace an SFTP server with Google cloud storage.

One of the methods is to recursively delete a directory, which could cause hundreds or thousands of deletes.

Using `StorageClient.DeleteObject` will cause one HTTP request for each delete.

I see that Google Cloud Storage has a *batch* API which can handle up to 100 operations in a batch.

Is it possible to perform batch operations from the C# client? (I cannot find any documentation on this).

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at [the documentation for the `dotnet` library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient.html#methods) , and trying it by myself, but it's not possible.

I would recommend opening an issue in the official [Github repository for the Google Cloud dotnet library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues), talking about this very same request.